# Porting a SFML game to the browser?

Tags: c++, sfml, browser-based-games, porting, browser

I've been messing around with SFML, it's my first experience with C++ and I'm enjoying it. But I'm wondering how to publish my game onto anything other than a native platform. Noting that this is my first time dealing with porting and C++, could anyone explain this to me as if I'm 5?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is quite broad, but here are some pointers to find out what you mean: If you want to *automatically port* game logic, you might like [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten#readme), an LLVM-to-JavaScript compiler.  You'll have to manually port the graphics code from SFML to [HTML canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)/[WebGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) though…  If you meant *porting it manually*, then get to work! :)  (Do you have a more specific thing bit you're stuck on?)

Comment: I'm really new to cross platform development, from what I understand sfml is a c++ specific library, so it can't be used in the browser, is there any application that will save me the hours of work porting it into html5 or flash? Emscriptem only ports game logic, and not the graphics code used for the game.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a list](http://www.sfml-dev.org/download/bindings.php) of all known SFML bindings. 
I work now for a few years with SFML but I've never heard about something like a web binding for browsers. If you are new to SFML and c++ you can probably look a bit arround and search for the best language/graphic libary which fit perfectly in your needs.